# Clarify directory quota and volume quota on RedHat

Tags: redhat, quota

I'm following this guide: [Managing Disk Quota](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Storage/2.0/html/Administration_Guide/chap-User_Guide-Dir_Quota.html)

But I really don't understand how to enable quota for every sub-directory inside a directory, when the containing directory doesn't have any limit.

For example:

- Directory A (all subdirs must be limited to 200MB)
- --- Directory A/a (size limit 200MB)
- --- Directory A/b (size limit 200MB)
- Directory B (all subdirs must be limited to 5GB)
- --- Directory B/a (size limit 5GB)
- --- Directory B/b (size limit 5GB)

In other words is it possible to inherit a size limit from the parent directory?

I found only some tutorials about setting up disk quota base on user/user group, but unfortunately that is not what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: So a directory `A/c` will _not_ have a quota applied?

Comment: @MichaelHampton:  Actually quota will be applied to all subdirs inside.

Comment: Then why don't you just apply the quota to `A` and have done?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Base on what I understand, if I limit size of `A`, then it would be limit size of `A` (contains all subdirs), is that correct?